# Issues with clearButtonMode, showing button for empty text

Tags: ios, swift, uitextfield

How do you get the clear button to appear on a UITextField when the placeholder is visible? The following works but is only visible when selected and text has been entered.

**Clear Button** (when text entered)

```
textField = UITextField(frame: someFrame);
textField.placeholder = "Untitled";
textField.clearButtonMode = .always;
textField.clearsOnBeginEditing = true;
```

How do you get the clear button to appear while editing and empty?

Comment: Why would you need the clear button if the text is empty?

Comment: lol, good point. I am in a learning phase with iOS and am reproducing an existing app, Awesome Note 2, which presents this feature for their note title entry field. I find the feature non-standard and a bit gross but was curious how they got this working

Comment: One way I found is to put a zero width character as the text whenever the text field is empty. But then this does not show the placeholder. Another way is to simply add a button as a subview of the text field and position it manually.